# How can I mount my non-VESA display on a VESA arm?

Tags: display, ergonomics, vesa

I have a non-VESA 21" LCD display from 2003, and I want to put it on a VESA arm. I figured I would at least find some sort of overpriced industrial solution for this, but so far I've found absolutely nothing. I'm either searching for the wrong thing or there just isn't a market for it.

**update:** the monitor is a [formac 2010](http://www.formac.com/webapp/products_displays_2010_x5.php)

Comment: Various industrial strength adhesives/epoxy's come to mind. 3M 5200 fast cure is one...http://www.shop3m.com/60980045581.html?WT.mc_ev=clickthrough&WT.mc_id=shop3m-AtoZ-Marine-Fast-Cure-5200-Adhesive-Sealant, G Flex is another...http://www.jamestowndistributors.com/userportal/show_product.do?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest but most dangerous way - Buy a drill and make a few holes.

Ugliest way but will work - use glue or sellotape.

After this, I am sorry, there just isn't a way I have seen apart from ugly harnesses that go around the entire monitor.

If I was you, the best thing you can do is buy a VESA mount monitor. If your monitor is from 2003, you will most likely be able to get a second hand monitor of higher specification that has a VESA mount for cheaper than any adapter/harness/whatever that you can buy.

Comment: you might want to reinforce the area behind the holes as well - most vesa mounts seem to have strips of thin metal as reinforcement behind it.

Comment: i updated the question with my monitor model

Comment: @william-hilsum -- do the ugly harnesses exist? i thought they would but i haven't been able to find them. My display's specs are just fine -- 21", 1600x1200, still looks gorgeous.

Comment: thats a bizarrely shaped system. That said,another alternative might be to find a CRT mount and use that

Answer (score 3):

JB Weld works.  Did this with both my HP 23in monitors which have no VESA holes.
Sand the paint off the ARM attachment if it has any and ruff up the surface a bit.
Mark the attachment point on the back of your monitor and use some course sandpaper to score the surface of your monitor.
Clean both surfaces with alcohol and let dry for a few minutes.
Mix the JB Weld per instructions. (Do this in a well ventilated area)
I probably over did the amount of JB Weld. I used about one tube per monitor!
The ARMs will never come off without tearing out the backs of the monitors, but the monitors are dedicated to a particular use in my sound studio and that is where they will stay. Food for thought before you mount the metal ARMs on your monitors . . . just saying.
Anyway, I considered several options and this one worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and ended up in this forum:

http://www.overclock.net/t/1200785/project-kapros-ikea-galant-pc-desk-mod/370#post_16677769

He basically makes a pair of metal pieces to mount his monitor.
[image: pair of metal pieces]
[image: Assembled]
[image: Mounted]

Comment: I've got a pair of LG W2361VG monitors with no VESA mount holes.  I'm totally going to give this a try!

Comment: Please let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

There are some adapters, these do not come with an arm this just makes them vesa compatible here is an amazon list. Not alot of people use them.

https://www.amazon.com/non-vesa-monitor-mounts/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Anon%20vesa%20monitor%20mounts

Comment: It isn't a 'bad' answer, but you could make it better by relying less on the amazon link. Add a picture, and talk about how it works, and it'll make your question a lot better. The audience *digs* pictures ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would first try searching for [VESA plate adapters](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http://www.standsandmounts.com/adapterplates.aspx&ei=_T8GT9gDpayxArmsgZEK&usg=AFQjCNFB86uSgSS5aPslkuWhSjfJighRLg) on Google. That turns up [this site](http://www.standsandmounts.com/adapterplates.aspx) which might have what you need. I don't really know the model of the monitor that you want to mount, but a search for any VESA adapters should get what you're looking for.

Comment: These adapter plates require that your screen actually supports VESA mounting — they just change the sizes. For example [this one](http://www.standsandmounts.com/premiermountsvesaadapterplatefor100mmx200mmufp-220.aspx) requires a VESA screen with 200x100 screw holes, and makes it work with a 75x75 mount.

Comment: What is the model of your monitor?

Comment: i updated the question with my monitor model